# Rack middleware and thread-safety

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thread-safety, rack, puma

I have a custom rack middleware used by my Rails 4 application. The middleware itself is just here to default `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers to `application/json` if the client did not provide a valid information (I'm working on an API). So before each request it changes those headers and after each request it adds a custom X-Something-Media-Type head with a custom media type information.

I would like to switch to Puma, therefore I'm a bit worried about the thread-safety of such a middleware. I did not play with instances variables, except once for the common `@app.call` that we encounter in every middleware, but even here I reproduced something I've read in RailsCasts' comments :

```
def initialize(app)
 @app = app
end

def call(env)
 dup._call(env)
end

def _call(env)
 ...
 status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
 ...
```

Is the `dup._call` really useful in order to handle thread-safety problems ?

Except that `@app` instance variable I only play with the current request built with the current env variable :

```
request      = Rack::Request.new(env)
```

And I call `env.update` to update headers and forms informations.

Is it dangerous enough to expect some issues with that middleware when I'll switch from `Webrick` to a concurrent web server such as `Puma` ?

If yes, do you know a handful way to make some tests en isolate portions of my middleware which are non-thread-safe ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's necessary to `dup` the middleware to be thread-safe. That way, anything instance variables you set from `_call` will be set on the duped instance, not the original. You'll notice that web frameworks that are built around Rack work this way:

- [Pakyow](https://github.com/metabahn/pakyow/blob/master/pakyow-core/lib/core/app.rb#L222)
- [Sinatra](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L893)

One way to unit test this is to assert that `_call` is called on a duped instance rather than the original.

Comment: As a corollary, iff you don't set/update instance variables it's not necessary to call `dup` on the middleware. Alternatively, use thread-safe data structures e.g. concurrent-ruby's cache map, for a shared cache.

Comment: found a good explanation from here: https://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2018-06-07-frozen-middleware-with-rack-freeze/